# Applications of Chow rings of classifying spaces in algebraic geometry

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, classifying-spaces, chow-groups

For an algebraic group $G$, the Chow ring of its classifying space $BG$, in the sense of

[Totaro, *The Chow ring of a classifying space*](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9802097)

has been computed in many cases. Is there any interesting application of these computations to classical problems in algebraic geometry?